# iMac G3 as an external screen

Tags: imac

I work as a teacher and I have a laptop model MacBook Pro.

I like retro technology, so I bought an iMac G3, it works perfectly.

I want to use iMac G3 like an extra screen for the laptop. I have a DVI converter, but it doesn’t work as I expect.

Is it possible to use iMac G3 as an external screen only?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible without hardware modification. The iMac G3 does not have a video input port; some (but not all) models have a VGA output port, but this cannot be used for input. Even if you could make it work, the maximum supported resolution of 1024x768 would probably be unusable with modern applications, which are likely to assume typical modern display resolutions (ie at least 1920x1080, being the most common resolution on desktop Macs, or even higher for modern MacBooks with "retina" displays).

Comment: Isn't there like an X forwarding thing you can do? Its possible on Linux, don't see why not on Mac OS.

Comment: @OmarL - Remote Desktop or VNC would be an option, but performance won't be great and the resolution will still be a problem, so I wouldn't recommend it.